# When automatically creating the table in PostgreSQL, Spring Boot application names the table name wrong if the name contains the dot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity as follows -

```
@Entity
@Table(name="abc.users")
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
}
```

In my application.properties I have set the following parameters

```
#postgres configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Once the application starts it creates the table name as `abc_users` instead of `abc.users` which was intended.

Following is the logline I see related to table creation when the application starts.

`Hibernate: create table abc_users (id uuid not null, password varchar(255) not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))`

It seems to hibernate is replacing the dot with the underscore.

I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere.

Comment: The dot is used between schema and table name. In your case abc would be schema and users the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not do this *by default* (at least Hibernate 6 does not).

If I have:

```java
    @Entity(name = "TestTableEntity")
    @Table(name = "test.table")
    public class TestTableEntity { ... }
```

Then, by default, Hibernate produces the following DDL with a quoted identifier:

```sql
    create table "test.table" ( ... )
```

However, my guess is that you have a custom naming strategy configured (most likely a `PhysicalNamingStrategy`), and the naming strategy is responsible for post-processing the table name.

P.S. I'm not sure, but I have in the back of my head that maybe Spring adds its own "opinionated" i.e. non-JPA-standard naming strategy by default, so if that's correct, you probably need to turn that off.

##### UPDATE

Yes, Spring is the culprit here, see here for more information:

https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/hibernate-naming-strategies-jpa-specification-vs-springboot-opinionation/

I *really* wish Spring would not do this sort of crap that goes against the JPA spec and the Hibernate documentation, leaving users confused, and getting in the way of people trying to map legacy database schemas.